# Freeswitch support for generating an SRTP offer from an incoming 3PCC INVITE?

Tags: c, webrtc, rtp, freeswitch, sdp

I'm using Freeswitch ESL (Event Socket Library) in Node.js
When I receive an invite to SIP.js from a classic sip endpoint the SDP content is regular RTP.
I need to be able to connect RTP endpoint to SRTP endpoint using Freeswitch in the middle.
In order to do so we need to be able create an endpoint on Freeswitch without SDP (3PCC INVITE) but we want this endpoint to return SRTP SDP and not RTP SDP.

**Main question: Does Freeswitch supports generating SRTP offer from an incoming 3PCC INVITE?**

I believe this is the part to handle 3PCC INVITE in Freeswitch 1.8.5:
https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/v1.8.5/src/mod/endpoints/mod_sofia/sofia.c

```
if (sofia_test_pflag(profile, PFLAG_3PCC)) {
    if (switch_channel_test_flag(channel, CF_PROXY_MODE) || switch_channel_test_flag(channel, CF_PROXY_MEDIA)) {
        switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_SESSION_LOG(session), SWITCH_LOG_INFO, "No SDP in INVITE and 3pcc=yes cannot work with bypass or proxy media, hanging up.\n");
        switch_channel_set_variable(channel, SWITCH_ENDPOINT_DISPOSITION_VARIABLE, "3PCC DISABLED");
        switch_channel_hangup(channel, SWITCH_CAUSE_MANDATORY_IE_MISSING);
    } else {
        switch_channel_set_variable(channel, SWITCH_ENDPOINT_DISPOSITION_VARIABLE, "RECEIVED_NOSDP");
        switch_core_media_choose_port(tech_pvt->session, SWITCH_MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, 0);
        switch_core_media_prepare_codecs(session, 1);
        switch_channel_set_state(channel, CS_HIBERNATE);
        switch_core_media_gen_local_sdp(session, SDP_TYPE_REQUEST, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
        sofia_set_flag_locked(tech_pvt, TFLAG_3PCC);

        if (sofia_use_soa(tech_pvt)) {
            nua_respond(tech_pvt->nh, SIP_200_OK,
                        SIPTAG_CONTACT_STR(tech_pvt->reply_contact),
                        SOATAG_USER_SDP_STR(tech_pvt->mparams.local_sdp_str),
                        SOATAG_REUSE_REJECTED(1),
                        SOATAG_AUDIO_AUX("cn telephone-event"),
                        TAG_IF(sofia_test_pflag(profile, PFLAG_DISABLE_100REL), NUTAG_INCLUDE_EXTRA_SDP(1)), TAG_END());
        } else {
            nua_respond(tech_pvt->nh, SIP_200_OK,
                        NUTAG_MEDIA_ENABLE(0),
                        SIPTAG_CONTACT_STR(tech_pvt->reply_contact),
                        SIPTAG_CONTENT_TYPE_STR("application/sdp"), SIPTAG_PAYLOAD_STR(tech_pvt->mparams.local_sdp_str), TAG_END());
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the same pattern they used for mod_verto can be used:
https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/v1.8.5/src/mod/endpoints/mod_verto/mod_verto.c

This function **switch_core_media_gen_local_sdp** seems to be the one to create the RTP SDP:
https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/v1.8.5/src/switch_core_media.c
How can we change this to SRTP SDP instead?

```
static const char *get_media_profile_name(switch_core_session_t *session, int secure)
{
    switch_assert(session);

    if (switch_channel_test_flag(session->channel, CF_AVPF)) {
        if (switch_channel_test_flag(session->channel, CF_DTLS) || secure) {
            if (switch_channel_test_flag(session->channel, CF_AVPF_MOZ)) {
                return "UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF";
            } else {
                return "RTP/SAVPF";
            }
        } else {
            if (switch_channel_test_flag(session->channel, CF_AVPF_MOZ)) {
                return "UDP/AVPF";
            } else {
                return "RTP/AVPF";
            }
        }
    }

    if (secure) {
        return "RTP/SAVP";
    }

    return "RTP/AVP";

}
```

There are 3 conditions to enable SRTP:

```
session->channel->flags['CF_AVPF']
(session->channel->flags['CF_DTLS'] || secure)
session->channel->flags['CF_AVPF_MOZ']
```

The conditions to put **CF_AVPF** flag are calling **switch_core_session_set_ice** or:

```
if (is_outbound || switch_channel_test_flag(session->channel, CF_RECOVERING) ||
    switch_channel_test_flag(session->channel, CF_3PCC)) {
    if (!switch_channel_test_flag(session->channel, CF_AVPF) &&
        switch_true(switch_channel_get_variable(session->channel, "media_webrtc"))) {
        switch_channel_set_flag(session->channel, CF_AVPF);
        switch_channel_set_flag(session->channel, CF_ICE);
        smh->mparams->rtcp_audio_interval_msec = SWITCH_RTCP_AUDIO_INTERVAL_MSEC;
        smh->mparams->rtcp_video_interval_msec = SWITCH_RTCP_VIDEO_INTERVAL_MSEC;
    }

    if (switch_true(switch_channel_get_variable(session->channel, "add_ice_candidates"))) {
        switch_channel_set_flag(session->channel, CF_ICE);
    }

    if ( switch_rtp_has_dtls() && dtls_ok(session)) {
        if (switch_channel_test_flag(session->channel, CF_AVPF) ||
            switch_true(switch_channel_get_variable(smh->session->channel, "rtp_use_dtls"))) {
            switch_channel_set_flag(smh->session->channel, CF_DTLS);
            switch_channel_set_flag(smh->session->channel, CF_SECURE);
            generate_local_fingerprint(smh, SWITCH_MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO);
        }
    }
    switch_core_session_parse_crypto_prefs(session);
    switch_core_session_check_outgoing_crypto(session);
}
```

The conditions to put **CF_DTLS** flag are the same as above (**CF_AVPF**) or calling **check_ice**:

```
if (switch_rtp_has_dtls() && dtls_ok(smh->session) && !strcasecmp(attr->a_name, "fingerprint") && !zstr(attr->a_value)) {
    char *p;

    engine->remote_dtls_fingerprint.type = switch_core_session_strdup(smh->session, attr->a_value);

    if ((p = strchr(engine->remote_dtls_fingerprint.type, ' '))) {
        *p++ = '\0';

        if (switch_channel_test_flag(smh->session->channel, CF_REINVITE) && !switch_channel_test_flag(smh->session->channel, CF_RECOVERING) &&
            !zstr(engine->remote_dtls_fingerprint.str) && !strcmp(engine->remote_dtls_fingerprint.str, p)) {
            engine->new_dtls = 0;
        } else {
            switch_set_string(engine->remote_dtls_fingerprint.str, p);
            engine->new_dtls = 1;
            engine->new_ice = 1;
        }
    }

    generate_local_fingerprint(smh, type);
    switch_channel_set_flag(smh->session->channel, CF_DTLS);

}
```

There is also the possibility to send true for the **secure** parameter but the conditions are many.

The conditions to put **CF_AVPF_MOZ** flag:

```
if (m->m_proto_name && !strcasecmp(m->m_proto_name, "UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF")) {
    switch_channel_set_flag(session->channel, CF_AVPF_MOZ);
}

if (m->m_proto_name && !strcasecmp(m->m_proto_name, "UDP/RTP/AVPF")) {
    switch_channel_set_flag(session->channel, CF_AVPF_MOZ);
}
```

Comment: So you want to call from regular SIP client to WebRTC(sip.js) with Freeswitch in the middle, right?

Comment: @os11k yes exactly what I tried to do.

Comment: You can do this, I have such solution in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set media_webrtc=true this should tell freeswitch to use DTLS for media stream, WebRTC signaling should be done separately.

```
<action application="bridge" data="[media_webrtc=true]sofia/internal/100%${sip_profile}"/>
```

Comment: 3PCC doesn't work like this on Freeswitch. The SDP is generated (in this case) before any application is run. And before any channel variables can be set.

Comment: What you mean? My command is for bridge which will send out invite with DTLS encryption, this is nothing to do with 3PCC. Maybe you can better explain what exactly you want? Why 3pcc is so critical? When I asked you under your question if you just want to connect SIP to WebRTC, you confirmed. This bridge command will do the job, but maybe I do not get your question.

Comment: I specifically asked for 3PCC INVITE in this question.
If you need to understand why you can check this issue on Github:
https://github.com/davehorton/drachtio-fsmrf/issues/39

Comment: All what I can say, that I have working sip.js with Freeswitch especially from SIP endpoint to WebRTC. I think problem is that you are copy-pasting my answer to other guy and you do not try to understand how this works.

Comment: When we handle the invite with ESL and not directly with Freeswitch it's not working. Can you see if it works for you with this module http://npmjs.com/package/modesl?

Comment: I think what you don't see is that with modesl we receive an INVITE from classic sip client with RTP SDP and then we want to INVITE a SIP.js client but for that we need SRTP SDP (even before we can bridge we need to create SRTP SDP on Freeswitch for the webRTC client INVITE and for that we need specifically 3PCC to handle INVITE without SDP content because we don't want the RTP SDP of the caller)
Then of course when we've got 2 endpoints one with RTP (caller) and the other SRTP (callee) we can bridge between those 2 endpoints to connect the call. hence the need for SRTP SDP for 3PCC INVITE

Comment: I think you can generate outgoing invite in any case(3PCC or not). If you want you can contact me directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213076/discussion-between-guy-messika-and-os11k).

Comment: I don't think this answer is eligible for the bounty as it's not the solution for the problem. Let me know what you think please and I will make a decision

Comment: I don't care about bounty :D But this is really strange that it didn't work for you. Good luck!